# How to debug deadlocks on linux server?

Tags: c++, linux, debugging

When I used to work with c# and windows, I could just dump process memory with `procdump -ma`  command, and than open the resulting dmp file in visual studio and quickly find where the deadlock occurs.

I'm looking to replicate this workflow in linux. I can create dump files with `gcore`. After this, how do I open such a file to see where each thread is? Is there a better way to do it?